# How to resolve http 500 when I use Jeddic

Tags: java, plugins

I had write a restful interface in NetbeansIDE8.2 ,and i have debug it with the PostMan App in chorme, and then an exception have experenced I will show the image down here :
[the HTTP ERROR 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3J4Ki.jpg)

and my code is here ,I have return a arryList to browser

```
@Path("/getStu")
@GET
public List<TfFreshstudent> queryStudentNoDomitory()
{
    List<TfFreshstudent> studentList= cq.queryFreshstudentNoDomitory();
    if (studentList.isEmpty()) {
        return studentList;
    }
    return null;
}
```

and I have tried other sub of the automatic create code ,and the error is also happened:

```
 @GET
public List<TfDormitory> getAllTfDormitories() {
    log.debug("REST request to get all TfDormitories");
    List<TfDormitory> tfDormitories = tfDormitoryFacade.findAll();
    return tfDormitories;
}
```

I have think that it maybe the return type error maybe ArryList can't be show on browser, maybe I must parse it to json type or response

Comment: a *500* is a server side error message.  In fact the `image` that you posted clearly states the some classes are missing

Answer (score 0):

**This is the entity which Jeddic was create**

```
package com.freshV3.cart.model;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name = "tf_dormitory")
public class TfDormitory {
@Column(name = "id", table = "tf_dormitory", nullable = false, length = 22)
@Id
private String id;

@Column(name = "buildName", table = "tf_dormitory", length = 50)
@Basic
private String buildName;

@Column(name = "comment", table = "tf_dormitory")
@Basic
private String comment;

@Column(name = "freshStudentId", table = "tf_dormitory", length = 22)
@Basic
private String freshStudentId;

@Column(name = "isDelete", table = "tf_dormitory")
@Basic
private Integer isDelete;

@Column(name = "operator", table = "tf_dormitory", length = 20)
@Basic
private String operator;

@Column(name = "roomCode", table = "tf_dormitory", length = 32)
@Basic
private String roomCode;

@Column(name = "roomId", table = "tf_dormitory")
@Basic
private String roomId;

public String getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getBuildName() {
    return this.buildName;
}

public void setBuildName(String buildName) {
    this.buildName = buildName;
}

public String getComment() {
    return this.comment;
}

public void setComment(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
}

public String getFreshStudentId() {
    return this.freshStudentId;
}

public void setFreshStudentId(String freshStudentId) {
    this.freshStudentId = freshStudentId;
}

public Integer getIsDelete() {
    return this.isDelete;
}

public void setIsDelete(Integer isDelete) {
    this.isDelete = isDelete;
}

public String getOperator() {
    return this.operator;
}

public void setOperator(String operator) {
    this.operator = operator;
}

public String getRoomCode() {
    return this.roomCode;
}

public void setRoomCode(String roomCode) {
    this.roomCode = roomCode;
}

public String getRoomId() {
    return this.roomId;
}

public void setRoomId(String roomId) {
    this.roomId = roomId;
}
```

}